# size of dimension of an N-dimensional cv::Mat

Tags: opencv

What is the right way to get the size of the N'th dimension of a cv::Mat object. In other words, what is the replacement for cvGetDimSize() in the new opencv?

Comment: What is problem with cvGetDimSize()? Function is still there. Checkout  [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#getdimsize).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`m.size.p[n]` will give you the n'th dimension,
but make sure that `n < m.dims`.

That is what `cvGetDimSize` does.